# Deprecated: Non-static method YRComms::convertEncodingUTF() should not be called statically,

Tags: php

I am getting tons of this error as a result of upgrading into PHP 5.6.

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in
>   (ADRESS) on line 686 Deprecated: Non-static method
>   YRComms::convertEncodingUTF() should not be called statically,
>   assuming $this from incompatible context in (ADRESS) on line 690

*(ADDRESS) means the PHP-file as I don't want to post the whole link here*

Here are some of the code:

Line 686

```
if(null==$name||''==trim($name))$name=array_pop(explode('/',$url));
```

Line 690

```
$name=YRComms::convertEncodingUTF($name);
```

Line 691

```
$name=YRComms::convertEncodingEntities($name);
```

Line 693

```
$url=YRComms::convertEncodingUTF($url);
```

And so on...

Any guesses on what I should do?

The php file can be found here: http://www.filedropper.com/yr
All the errors can be found here: http://www.filedropper.com/errorfromyr

Comment: You're calling a non-static method statically.

Comment: Thank you for commenting, @Halfstop. Yes, I understand that. Also understand that this must be an annoying post, but I don't get it. Is it dangerous that it is this way, should I change anything, or should I just leave it? If this post seems to annoying I will delete it.

Comment: It's that your code is broken and should be fixed. PHP 5.6 is more strict about such things. I don't know what your PHP code looks like, but using $this-> instead of YRComms:: is what you should probably be doing.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I will post a link to the PHP if you have time and want to look at it.

Comment: Side note: You know that "Deprecated" means that you should not be using it anymore right? There should be a new function or method which does what you want in a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Line 686

Change this line

```
if(null==$name||''==trim($name))$name=array_pop(explode('/',$url));
```

to this

```
if(null==$name||''==trim($name)) {
    $name = explode('/',$url);
    $name = end($name);
}
```

Line 690,691,693

Change these lines

```
$name=YRComms::convertEncodingUTF($name);
$name=YRComms::convertEncodingEntities($name);
// Clean URL
$url=YRComms::convertEncodingUTF($url);
```

to this

```
$obj = new YRComms();
$name=$obj->convertEncodingUTF($name);
$name=$obj->convertEncodingEntities($name);
// Clean URL
$url=$obj->convertEncodingUTF($url);
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Halfstop said you call non-static method statically.

I don't know how YrComms is build. If it's normal class with constructor then you need do something like

`$obj = new YRComms(); $obj->convertEncodingUTF($url);`

if it's singleton then you need do something like

```
YRComms::getInstance()->convertEncodingUTF($url);
```

I cannot help you more without knowing definition of YRComms class.

Comment: Thank you. I will post the php file if you have time and want to look at it.

Comment: I've checked it as I suggested u can use first of my example and it will work. This class uses very old PHP4 syntax so be careful using it.

Comment: I have tried your method now, but I am not sure where to put it, and if I should delete some of the old code? Thank you for the patience.

Comment: ok do soemthing else find line `public function convertEncodingUTF(){` and change it to `public static function convertEncodingUTF(){`

Comment: Still nothing... :( Any other suggestions? (sorry for answering so late...)